# Angles on a circle

Tags: math, geometry, degrees, angle

I am trying to work out some circle detection and I'm having trouble working out some angles, can anyone tell me how to get the angle value of these blue angles. [image]

I have never worked with angles before, so can someone point me to some relevant functions, algorithms etc.

Comment: You'll have better luck at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, you haven't given us any details about what information you have? What are the red circles?  What do you know about them?

Answer (score 4):

The external angles of a polygon sum to 360 degrees, so if you have a regular polygon with N vertices then each external angle would be `360 / N`.

In your example above `N = 8`, so assuming the points are equally spaced, the external angles are each `360 / 8 = 45` degrees.